# Selenium: Using regular expression with getLocation

Tags: regex, ant, hudson, selenium-rc

I was using Selenium RC some time back and the statement below worked fine:

```
verifyEquals("*/en-us/", selenium.getLocation());
```

Now I am using Hudson, Ant and SeleniumRC and this statement does not work. I am getting a message:

> org.junit.comparisonFailure: expected:"*/en-us/" but was
>   "http://www.testwebsite.com/en-us/".

It does not seem to consider `"*/en-us/"` as a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

I found some info in this [blog](http://automationtricks.blogspot.com/2010/05/selenium-regular-expression-and-pattern.html)

`verifyEquals("*/en-us/", selenium.getLocation());`

is a *global pattern* and should be fine (well this is what you have and for some reason doesn't work)

`verifyEquals("regexp:^.*/en-us/$", selenium.getLocation());`

is a *regular expression pattern* that should do the same.

check the *global pattern* solution once more for typos or give the *regular expression* solution a try.
hope this will help.

**update**

(it's kind of guessing now... found something (un)related [here](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/SeleneseTestCase.html#seleniumEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29))

try `seleniumEquals` insted of `verifyEquals`

Comment: I tried verifyEquals("regexp:^.*/en-us/$", selenium.getLocation()); and I still get the same error. I am not able to make any regular expression work.